# What is the difference between session_unset and unset($_SESSION) in PHP?

Tags: php, variables, session, unset

What is the difference between unsetting session variables with session_unset and unset($_SESSION)?

It's not a duplicate question, as all other questions are talking about the difference between session_unset and session_destroy !

Comment: what did the manuals say on PHP.net and/or Google?

Comment: They are all talking about session_unset and session_destroy !

Comment: `Caution 
Do NOT unset the whole $_SESSION with unset($_SESSION) as this will disable the registering of session variables through the $_SESSION superglobal. `

Answer (score 2):

`session_unset()` Frees all session variables.

Do NOT unset the whole `$_SESSION` with `unset($_SESSION)` as this will disable the registering of session variables through the `$_SESSION` superglobal.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php